# Java Currency does not display USD currency symbol

Tags: java, locale, currency

I am attempting to use `java.util.Currency` to display the currency symbol for the specified currency code. The following works for the Uk currency code `GBP`:

```
final Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("GBP");
final String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
System.out.println(symbol);
```

Which outputs `£`.

But the following does not work:

```
final Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("USD");
final String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
System.out.println(symbol);
```

Which outputs `USD`.

I was expecting it to output `$`. Why has this not worked?

I noticed that `getSymbol()` uses the systems default locale. Is it possible to derive the locale from the currency code?

Comment: It prints `$` for me.

Comment: @crm, In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Community Edition) I see `$`, maybe the problem is in your terminal or IDE?

Comment: The documentation of `Currency#getSymbol` also states "For example, for the US Dollar, the symbol is "$" if the default locale is the US, while for other locales it may be "US$". If no symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217 currency code is returned." - I suspect your Locale is something different.

Comment: It depends on the Locale being used, try getSymbol(Locale)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol for a currency might be different depending on what your Locale is.  So whatever your default locale is displays USD as the symbol.  Suggest using `Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);` instead of `Currency.getInstance("USD");`